# AllowAnonymous not allowing anonymous access in mvc 4 web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I have an mvc4 web application with 4 controllers.  Two of the controllers should allow anyone to access the methods but no matter what method I try I always get redirected to the login page.  Here's an example of one of the controllers.

```
[Authorize]
public class TrainersController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebinarTrainerRepository _trainerRepository;

    public TrainersController(IWebinarTrainerRepository trainerRepository)
    {
        _trainerRepository = trainerRepository;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new IndexListViewModel {Trainers = _trainerRepository.List()};
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Solution: Since this is my first time using forms authentication, everything I was doing came from multiple articles the google recommended.  In one of them they had to put this in the web.config file.

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I later found that this is not needed, and causes problems, in mvc4.  Removing it took care of the problem.